# Add swipe in List component Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, list, swipe

I have a list component in my app which shows some tiles and one can navigate through them horizontally and i was wondering how can i add the swipe functionality in it to the left or to the right,is this supported by default when the app is on a touch device? the list is like:

```
<s:List id="list2" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{ recordingsShown }"
                preinitialize="list2_preinitializeHandler(event)"
                selectedIndex="0" visible="false">

            <s:layout>

                <s:TileLayout id="tilelayout"
                              useVirtualLayout="true"
                              orientation="columns" 
                              columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth" rowAlign="justifyUsingHeight"
                              requestedColumnCount="3"
                              requestedRowCount="2"
                              paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5"
                              verticalGap="10" horizontalGap="10" />

            </s:layout>

</s:List>
```

any help?

Comment: IT should be supported by default on a touch device; or at least when using the mobile skin.  Have you tried it?  What problems did you have?

Comment: what do you mean using the mobile skin? No i haven't tried it, its a desktop app for the time being but it will be put on a touchscreen that's why i make these thoughts...So list supports going back and forth by default in a touch interface right?

Comment: Ahh, now we're getting there! Desktop app was the info that was missing here! You're confusing swipe with a normal scroll effect. Swipe is usually flicking pages/items/you name it using two or more fingers. For the tiles to scroll on a mobile device, you need to wrap it in a scroller.

Comment: By mobile Skin, I mean create a mobile project and/or manually switch your project to use the mobile skin.  I do not believe the Spark skins are optimized for touch.  So, whether it works or not depends on how the hardware sends events to your flash runtime. you haven't really told us if you're having a problem yet. @user1069487 The List class has a scroller built in; you shouldn't need to wrap it.

Comment: Right, missed the List part of the code. Was a little too focussed on the TileLayout.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com thank u for the answer but how can i switch my project into mobile project? and if i do that do i need to add eventlisteners to the list in order to view the items?

Comment: You can change the theme to the mobile theme using a compiler argument. I don't think you can change the "behavior" on a Flash Builder project to add "mobile".

Comment: i want to support something like this: [http://thanksmr.com/examples/androidscroll/AndroidScroll.swf](http://thanksmr.com/examples/androidscroll/AndroidScroll.swf) when the user swipes...how can i achieve that given the list above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
list2.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe)
```

?

That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes the question is what to do onSwipe in order to show some more items??

Comment: I think you have to clarify your question as it isn't really clear what you're trying to achieve with the swipe gesture. Do you simply want to add more items to the TileLayout on swipe?

Comment: Why not use a simple scroller then? I still don't fully understand your question. Could you maybe provide your code to pinpoint your issue?

Comment: my code is the above... i render some items and i was wondering if i swipe over these will it scroll by default in a touch interface or should i declare that somehow in my list?i want to avoid clicking the scroller and dragging it..thats why i ask!i think i made it clear now...